# Comment traduiriez-vous le proverbe anglais « there’s honor among thieves »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, proverbes

Le *New American Oxford Dictionary* dit de ce proverbe :

> **there's honor among thieves:** (proverb) dishonest people may have certain standards of behavior that they will respect.

Je cherche non pas une traduction proche du texte et jolie, mais plutôt un proverbe français sur le même thème. J'ai parfois entendu dire *« les loups ne s'entredévorent jamais »*, mais je ne sais pas si c'est une expression courante. Je ne suis même pas sûr que ça ait le même sens, en fait.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

J'ai plutôt entendu *Les loups ne se mangent pas entre eux* mais qui (pour moi) veut plus dire qu'un malfrat aura tendance à éviter de s'attaquer à un autre malfrat, mais pas forcément par respect d'un quelconque code. Il semble d'ailleurs que *Dog does not eat dog* existe pour ce sens-là.

On a ensuite dans beaucoup de films, les vieux mafieux qui parlent du célèbre *code d'honneur* qu'ils respectaient et que les jeunes bandits ne respectent plus. Ton expression semble plutôt parler de ce code d'honneur-là mais je ne vois aucune expression en français qui pourrait utiliser ce sens-là.

Comment: merci pour la réponse. J'ai corrigé les tirets manquant dans “ce sens-là” et les autres.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *dog does not eat dog* en anglais. On dit plutôt *dog eat dog* quand il s'agit d'une situation impitoyable.

Comment: @Andrew J'ai vu ça [ici](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Dog+does+not+eat+dog). Maintenant il est possibles que cet expression soit très rarement voire pas du tout utilisée en EN.

Answer (score 9):

Ce qui est amusant c'est qu'en Français, nous aurions tendance à dire le contraire : "*Il n'y a pas d'honneur parmi les voleurs*".

Sinon, comme souvent il n'existe pas forcément de traduction portant exactement le même sens, et effectivement "*les loups ne se dévorent/mangent jamais/pas entre eux* " serait une des expressions les plus proche en sens.

Answer (score 7):

[Certains](http://www.languagerealm.com/french/frenchproverbs_l.php) ne se privent pas de traduire directement par *les loups ne se mangent pas entre eux*. Je pense qu'on n'aura pas beaucoup mieux.

Answer (score 0):

Dans un contexte mafieux, ce proverbe pourrait rappeler un certain [code d'honneur issu de la culture sicilienne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosa_Nostra). Je proposerais donc une phrase qu'on retrouve souvent :

> Il y a un code d'honneur dans les mafias.

Comment: Souvent, souvent…

Answer (score 0):

Compter sur un voleur dépourvu d'honneur à votre péril.

Answer (score 0):

"Honneur" dans ce context est plus précisément traduit en "Loyauté". Ainsi on peut traduire le proverbe Americain comme suit:"il n'existe pas de loyauté parmi les malfrats". Ou bien: "un voleur n'est loyal qu'à lui seul"

Comment: Pas d'accord pour traduire "there's honor among thieves" par "il n'existe pas de loyauté parmi les malfrats". Ca semble plutôt le contraire.